# Build a set of objects and place them into a tuple

Tags: c++, macros, tuples, c-preprocessor

Basically what I need to do is something like this:

```
int a = 1;
float q = 3.3;
char g = 'e';

// ... other useful variables...

auto my_tuple = std::make_tuple(a, q, g/*, ... and so on... */);
```

Now, I always fear about forgetting to add my variables to my_tuple, and it is quite boring to both add a variable and add the variable to the tuple every time I need to add a new variable.

So I was wondering if there is any way to do something like this with macros. As an example I could do

```
#define DECLARE_VARIABLE(t, n, v) t n = v;
```

But this only creates the variable. Is there any way to add something like

```
#define END_OF_VARIABLES .....
```

so that I can write

```
DECLARE_VARIABLE(int, a, 1)
DECLARE_VARIABLE(float, q, 3.3)
DECLARE_VARIABLE(char, g, 'e')
// ...

END_OF_VARIABLES
```

And my_tuple gets built automatically?
I could accept also similar solutions that lead to the same result, as an example also

```
DECLARE_ALL_VARIABLES_AND_BUILD_MY_TUPLE(int, a, 1, float, q, 3.3, char, g, 'e'/*...*/)
```

would be fine as well.

Is it possible at all to do something like this?

Comment: What you are doing is logically redundant. The values of a, q and g are available in the tuple through std::get<>(). You don't need to store copies.

Comment: Do you need both the variables and the tuple for some reason? If not, then `auto my_tuple = make_tuple(int(1), etc);`

Comment: Actually, it IS redundant! But my code needs to be decently usable from others, and I would like them to be able to use their own names instead of having to remember the number of each variable. If I could just build a tuple and make a define that maps their names to get <N> (my_tuple) that would go as well! But I can't ask my users to remember dozens of ids, using names is much more easy!

Comment: Use an enum that maps N to a meaningful name. Then the can std::get<ID_A>() etc. No macros required!

Comment: But then how can I build the enum, at the end of all declarations? Or can I append an object to an enum? This just makes the question identical to the tuple case!

Comment: [Example of what I mean](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66d5fa77ba203ba6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way to go about things. There is a direct solution at the bottom, but before we get to that: Things I would consider instead:

- Use a struct/class instead of a tuple
- Use an enum to make the tuple elements more readably accessible
- Use an accessor class that maps tuple elements to meaningfully named getter functions
- Use meaningfully named accessor functions that accept a tuple as parameter

If you're still sure you want to do this with the preprocessor: there exists [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), and with it, all sorts of more or less crazy preprocessor tricks become possible. You could do the thing you wanted like this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define DECLARE_VARIABLE(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, elem) = BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 2, elem);
#define ISOLATE_VARNAME(r, data, elem) (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, elem))

#define VARSEQ ((int, x, 2)) ((char, g, 'a')) ((double, y, 2.0))

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_VARIABLE, _, VARSEQ)
auto mytuple = std::make_tuple(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(ISOLATE_VARNAME, _, VARSEQ)));
```

Here `VARSEQ` is what Boost.PP calls a *sequence* of what it calls *tuple*s. A sequence is something of the form

```
(a)(b)(c)
```

And a tuple is something of the form

```
(a, b, c)
```

The "functions" I used are

- `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM` extracts an element from a tuple
- `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` applies a macro to all elements of a sequence
- `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM` lists all elements of a sequence with commas between them

For details consult the link to the documentation above.

The implementation is open source and an interesting read if you're completely bonkers, by the way; they really had to make do with what the preprocessor gave them. Loops are emulated with long cascades of numbered macros, where one expands to the thing it's supposed to do and the next macro in the cascade to continue the loop, and the `BOOST_PP_ITERATE` stuff where one file is `#include`d several times with different macro definitions for flow control is one of the niftiest tricks never to use in production code I have ever seen.